# Una pregunta acerca de como se lee los strings en c++

Tags: c++, windows, lista, programación-funcional

En estos momentos estaba haciendo una lista doblemente ligada y cuando empece a probarla tuve un problema a la hora de leer los `strings` , no pude hacer que en la sección `temp->nombre` pudiera leer el salto de linea , ejemplo si quería poner un nombre como "Juan Manuel" el programa solo leía la primera e ignoraba las demás  entradas de texto . Tengo entendido que se necesita usar `getline()` para esto ¿pero como? ya lo he intentado y resulta lo mismo

Podrian ayudarme a poder resolver esto .

```
cout<<" Dame tu nombre "<<endl;
 cin>>temp->nombre;
cin.ignore();

 cout<<" Dame tu apellido "<<endl;
 cin>>temp->apellido;
 cin.ignore();
 cout<<" Dame tu ID"<<endl;
 cin>>temp->id;
 cout<<" Dame tu Ruta"<<endl;
 cin>>temp->ruta;
 temp->num++;
 lista->anterior=temp;
    temp->siguiente=lista;
lista=temp;


}
cout<<"\t \t Conductor numero ["<<temp->num<<"]"<<endl;
cout<<"\t \t El nombre es : -> "<<lista->nombre<<endl;
cout<<"\t \t El Apellido es : -> "<<lista->apellido<<endl;
cout<<"\t \t El Id es  -> "<<lista->id<<endl;
cout<<"\t \t La ruta es : -> "<<lista->ruta<<endl;
return lista;
```

Aquí esta el código completo , por si les ayuda .

https://pastebin.com/CrQg441F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tengo entendido que se necesita usar `getline()` para esto ¿pero como? ya lo he intentado y resulta lo mismo.

Veamos. Si tu tienes este código:

```
cout<<" Dame tu nombre "<<endl;
cin>>temp->nombre;
cin.ignore();
```

Lo que sucede es que el programa va a almacenar en nombre únicamente la primera palabra... Si quieres que se almacene toda la línea entonces sabes que has de usar `getline()`. La primera aproximación podría quedar así:

```
cout<<" Dame tu nombre "<<endl;
getline(cin,temp->nombre);
cin.ignore();
```

Pero resulta que a veces el programa no funciona porque no se lee nada. ¿Qué está sucendiendo?

Pasa que las lecturas comunes ( `cin >> variable` ) no suelen eliminar el salto de línea que sigue a la variable a leer y, en consecuencia, la función `getline` lee una cadena vacía (el primer caracter que se encuentra es el salto de línea y ahí entiende que debe dejar de leer).

La solución pasa por limpiar el buffer antes de llamar a `getline()`:

```
cout<<" Dame tu nombre "<<endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,temp->nombre);
```

Comment: Gracias , solo tuve que poner 

cout<<" Dame tu nombre "<<endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,temp->nombre);

una vez, osea cin.ignore() una vez

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es obtener la información de la siguiente manera:

```
string variable;
getline(cin, variable);
```

De esta manera ya podrás obtener toda la linea.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XNmQB

Parece que no funciona

Comment: Según la [Documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) debe funcionar, estás agregando todas las librerías

Comment: Usar `getline()` es correcto, lo que te está pasando es que antes de usar esa función seguro usaste un `cin`, el cual no te escapa el ultimo \n. Hace un `cin >> variableInutil` antes de usar `getline` para eliminar ese caracter y vas a ver que empieza a funcionar de 10! Saludos! P.D: acá hay una pregunta que toca el tema y seguro te puede ayudar más que yo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin

Comment: @Genarito hay formas mucho más elegantes de conseguir ese efecto sin recurrir a variables dummy....

Comment: Excelente! Gracias por la respuesta